# Use Index and Match with multiple lookup values to get a single result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using `INDEX` & `MATCH`, I'm trying to copy some data across from one worksheet to another (both of which are in the same workbook). I want to grab the description of an item via its ID and it's subset lettering.

**EXAMPLE:**

Sheet 1 (Destination)

```
             Formula goes here
                     ↓
   +------+---+---------------
   |  A   | B |      C
---+------+---+---------------
 1 | R976 | A | Lazy Brown Dog
 2 | R976 | F | Grey Bird
 3 | R976 | D | Fox
```

Sheet 2 (Source)

```
   |  A   |    B   | C |      D
---+------+--------+---+---------------
 1 |  ID  | Subset |   | Description
---+------+--------+---+---------------
 2 | R976 |    A   |   | Lazy Brown Dog
 3 | R976 |    D   |   | Fox
 4 | R976 |    F   |   | Grey Bird
```

I want the formula in column `C` of Sheet 1 to grab the description from column `D` of Sheet 2, based off the ID in column `A` and the unique letter in column `B`.

Current:

```
=INDEX(A1:A4,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A2:C4, 0))
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
=INDEX(A1:A4,MATCH(A1&B1,Sheet2!A2:C4, 0))
```

However, I'm getting an `#NA` even after using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: That worked amazingly! Thank you for the edit. What I forgot to include was the reference if there are two R976 with the letter A, however column C defines the difference between them. How would I grab the description in sheet 1 Column D?

Comment: Oh come on, put a bit of effort in!  The formula I gave you concatenates columns A and B.  What do you think you need to change to make it concatenate columns A and B and C?

Comment: FROM  
 MATCH(Sheet1!$A1&Sheet1!$B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5,0)  **TO** MATCH(Sheet1!$A1&Sheet1!$B1&Sheet1!$C1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5&&Sheet2!$C$1:$C$5,0) ?

Comment: @Anna Yep - you got it. :)  (Well nearly - you seem to have put two ampersands prior to `Sheet2‌​!$C$1:$C$5`, but that might have just been an accident as you typed it into the comment)

Comment: @YowE3K ahh, yes it was a typo. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want Sheet1!C2 to have a formula of:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2&Sheet1!$B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4,0))}
```

Then copy that down to cells C3 and C4.